# Fasttext inconsistent on one label model classification

Tags: python-3.x, fasttext

I'm using official FastText python library (v0.9.2) for intents classification.

```py
import fasttext

model = fasttext.train_supervised(input='./test.txt',
  loss='softmax',
  dim=200,
  bucket=2000000,
  epoch=25,
  lr=1.0)
```

Where test.txt contains just one sample file like:

```
__label__greetings hi
```

and predict two utterances the results are:

```py
print(model.words)
print('hi', model.predict('hi'))
print('bye', model.predict('bye'))
```

```
app_1  | ['hi']
app_1  | hi (('__label__greetings',), array([1.00001001]))
app_1  | bye ((), array([], dtype=float64))
```

This is my expected output, meanwhile if a set two samples for the same label:

```
__label__greetings hi
__label__greetings hello
```

The result for OOV is not correct.

```
app_1  | ['hi', '</s>', 'hello']
app_1  | hi (('__label__greetings',), array([1.00001001]))
app_1  | bye (('__label__greetings',), array([1.00001001]))
```

I understand that the problem is with `</s>` token, maybe `\n` in text file?, and when there isn't any word on vocabulary the text is replaced by `</s>`. There are any train option or way to skip this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastText is a big, data-hungry algorithm that starts with random-initialization. You shouldn't expect results to be sensible or indeed match any set of expectations on toy-sized datasets - where (for example) 100%-minus-epsilon of your n-gram buckets won't have received any training.

I also wouldn't expect `supervised` mode to ever reliably predict no labels on realistic data-sets – it expects all of its training data to have labels, and I've not seen mention of its use to predict an implied 'ghost' category of "not in training data" versus a single known label (as in '[one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification)').

(Speculatively, I think you might have to feed FastText `supervised` mode explicitly `__label__not-greetings` labeled contrast data – perhaps just synthesized random strings if you've got nothing else – in order for it to have any hope of meaningfully predicting "not-greetings".)

Given that, I'd not consider your first result for the input `bye` correct, nor the second result not correct. Both are just noise results from an undertrained model being asked to make a kind of distinction it's not known for being able to make.

Comment: thank you for your response, I understand your point, fasttext is another text classifier model after all, my confusion was because i used nodejs (binding) implementation and work like I exposed, after I read your comment I check the implementation itself and previous to the prediction it check if tokens are in vocabulary. Thank again for you clarification.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to gojomo's answer, we can say that your training **dataset** is absolutely **too small**.

If you don't have a significant annotated dataset, you can try **zero shot classification**: starting from a pretrained language model, you only set some labels and let the model try to classify sentences.

[Here](https://huggingface.co/zero-shot/) you can see and test an interesting demo.

Read also this [good article](https://joeddav.github.io/blog/2020/05/29/ZSL.html) about zero shot classification, with theory and implementation.